# Combine columns in a DataFrame through a function or class

Tags: python, pandas

I have 3 columns: days, months, hours, to build a new column (Series) referring to a date, where year is a constant input (i.e. 2020). There is a way to do this using single values: I would use datetime class and input int's. Yet, how do I do it using Series input instead of int's?
Thanks in advance

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

days_lst = ['days', 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 3]
hours_lst = ['hours', 0, 12, 0, 12, 0, 12]
months_lst = ['months', 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]
year = 2020
df1 = pd.DataFrame(days_lst[1:], columns=['days'])
df1[hours_lst[0]] = pd.Series(hours_lst[1:])
df1[months_lst[0]] = pd.Series(months_lst[1:])
df1['year'] = 2020
df1['date'] = datetime(year=df1['year'], month=df1['months'], day=df1['days'], hour=['hours'])
```

By trying last line I get the following error:

```
raise TypeError("cannot convert the series to " "{0}".format(str(converter)))
```

Comment: Please include what you have tried so far in your question. SO is not a "code-factory" to write your code. See [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Also please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: What is wrong with your code? Is it giving wrong output or some error? Include that info to your question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like using [`pd.to_datetime`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/timeseries.html#assembling-datetime-from-multiple-dataframe-columns):

```
df1['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1[['year','months','days','hours']])
```